# Get product parent name from child product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-collection

I have a product model from order item model, which i call like this:

```
$product = $orderItem->getProduct();
```

The problem is one of the order item is a child product from configurable product, i need to retrieve the parent name from this product, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$productId = 1; //this is child product id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
if(isset($product[0])){
  $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product[0]);
    echo $product->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Get Parent Product from Child Id.**

```
protected $_productloader;
protected $configurable;
protected $grouped;
protected $bundleSelection;

public function __construct(
    ...........................................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable,
    \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped $grouped,
    \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type $bundleSelection,
    ...........................................................
) {
    ...........................................................
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    $this->configurable = $configurable;
    $this->grouped = $grouped;
    $this->bundleSelection = $bundleSelection;
    ...........................................................
}

...........................................................
...........................................................
...........................................................

public function getParentProductData($productData)
{
    $prdData = '';
    $parentProductId = $this->getParentProductId($productData->getEntityId());
    if ($parentProductId) {
        $prdData = $this->_productloader->create()->load($parentProductId);
    } else {
        $prdData = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productData->getEntityId());
    }
    // parent Product Data
    return $prdData;
}

public function getParentProductId($childId)
{
    $parent_id = 0;
    // configurable product
    $product = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    if (isset($product[0])) {
        $parent_id = $product[0];
        return $parent_id;
    }
    // group product
    $groupIds = $this->grouped->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    if (isset($groupIds[0])) {
        $parent_id = $groupIds[0];
        return $parent_id;
    }
    // bundel product
    $budel_id = $this->bundleSelection->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    if (isset($budel_id[0])) {
        $parent_id = $budel_id[0];
        return $parent_id;
    }
    return $parent_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
protected $_catalogProductTypeConfigurable;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,       
    //for getting parent id of simple
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $catalogProductTypeConfigurable,
    array $data = []
) {
    //for getting parent id of simple
    $this->_catalogProductTypeConfigurable = $catalogProductTypeConfigurable;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
public function getProductData($id){
    $productId = $orderItem->getProduct()->getId();
    $parentByChild = $this->_catalogProductTypeConfigurable->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
    if(isset($parentByChild[0])){
        //set id as parent product id...
        $id = $parentByChild[0];          
    }
    return $id;     
}
```

Alternatively, you can use this too:

```
$productId = $orderItem->getProduct()->getId(); //this is child product id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
 if(isset($product[0])){
     //this is parent product id..
     echo $product[0];
}
```

Comment: then how can i get the product parent name?

Comment: Use the above mentioned code after your code $product = $orderItem->getProduct();

As it will return product id, now you can load the product name by loading product factory.

Answer (score 0):

`$orderItem->getName()` should return the parents name for a configurable product.

Comment: not returning the parents name

Comment: ok, please provide a bit more context then in your question. where do you get the orderItem from etc.

Comment: from order collection in Magento_Customer/view/frontend/templates/account/order/history.phtml

Comment: what Magento version are you running? I don't have that in 2.1.11